# How to pass client Id and client secret to a method while calling Junit

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to write a test case for a method which calls a service with client Id and client Secret.But i am getting nullpointer exception from the Junit.I am not able to pass the clientId and client secret using Junit below is my code

```
  @Service
 public class ourClientServiceImpl implements ourClientService {

private static final Logger ourClientServiceLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ourClientServiceImpl.class);

@Value("${service-description.our-service.base-url}")
private String ourServiceBaseUrl;

@Value("${service-description.posting-service.subscription-key}")
private String subscriptionKey;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("clientRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate clientRestTemplate;


@Value("${token.scope}")
private String scope;

@Value("${token.grantType}")
private String grantType;

@Autowired
private PingfedConfig config;

/**
 * Method to fetch our Name based on our Number
 *
 * @param ourNumber ourNumber
 * @return our Details
 */
@Override
public ourResponse fetchDetailsClient(String ourNumber) {
    ourClientServiceLogger.info("Fetching our name for our number::{}", ourNumber);
    final String resourceUrl = ourServiceBaseUrl + "/our?our-number=" + ourNumber;
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(resourceUrl);
    UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build().encode();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + getJWTAuthenticationToken());
    ResponseEntity<ourResponse> ourServiceResponseResponse = clientRestTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers),
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<ourResponse>() {
            });
    return ourServiceResponseResponse.getBody();
}

private String getJWTAuthenticationToken() {
    ourClientServiceLogger.info("Getting the JWT token");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    headers.setBasicAuth(config.getClientId(), config.getClientSecret());
    HttpEntity formEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    ResponseEntity<JWTTokenResponse> jwtToken = clientRestTemplate.exchange(config.getTokenUrl() + "?grant_type=client_credentials&Scope=openid", HttpMethod.POST, formEntity, JWTTokenResponse.class);
    if (jwtToken != null && jwtToken.getBody() != null) {
        return jwtToken.getBody().getAccessToken();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

The jUnit class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OurClientServiceTest {

private final OurResponse expectedOurResponse = OurResponse.builder().eourNumber("15253").ourName("New").build();
private static final String jwtMockToken = "Bearer vgftyuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu";
private final JWTTokenResponse jwtTokenResponse = JWTTokenResponse.builder().tokenType("Bearer").expiresIn("Now").extExpiresIn("Now").expiresOn("Now").notBefore("Now").resource("Now").accessToken(jwtMockToken).build();
@InjectMocks
private OurClientServiceImpl ourClientService;
@Mock
@Qualifier("clientRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate clientRestTemplate;

@Autowired
private PingfedConfig config;

OurResponse ourResponse  = OurResponse.builder().ourNumber("15253").build();
ResponseEntity<OurResponse> ourResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(ourResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
ResponseEntity<JWTTokenResponse> jwtTokenResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(jwtTokenResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

@Before
public void setJwtTokenResponseEntity() {
    when(clientRestTemplate.exchange(
            anyString(),
            any(HttpMethod.class),
            any(HttpEntity.class),
            eq(JWTTokenResponse.class))).thenReturn(jwtTokenResponseEntity);
}


@Test
public void testFetchOurDetailsClient() {
    
    when(clientRestTemplate.exchange(
            anyString(),
            any(HttpMethod.class),
            any(HttpEntity.class),
            eq(VendorResponse.class))).thenReturn(ourResponseEntity);
        OurResponse actualResponse = ourClientService.fetchVendorDetailsClient("15253");
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedOurResponse.getVendorNumber(), actualOurResponse.getOurNumber());
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedOurResponse.getVendorName(), actualOurResponse.getOurName());
}



}
```

Please let me know where i am doing wrong .Thanks in advance

Comment: "*I am not able to pass the clientId and client secret using Junit*" - Why not?

Comment: Could you include the entire class? I see the `config` used but if it's null, I suppose that it's not correctly injected

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel the impl class you mean ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel edited my post in Impl class i am reading the config from yml file

Comment: @Turing85 It's getting NULLPointer from the Junit